# How to update multiple rows include with-select sentence in Oracle

Tags: oracle, select, sql-update, multiple-columns

I want update table_a 's col1 with a value from another table.

I make a select that is

```
with tmp as (
 blar~
)
select col1 from table_b b, tmp t
where 1=1
and b.col2 = t.col_x
```

Update join condition

```
 table_a.col3 = table_b.col3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle is to create an updateable view like this:

```
update 
    ( with tmp as ( select col2 
                    from table_c)
    select a.col1 as a_col1
           , b.col1 as b_col1
           , a.id as a_id
    from tmp
         join table_b b
             on b.col2 = tmp.col2
         join table_a a
             on a.col3 = b.col3
     ) t
set a_col1 = b_col1
/
```

The important points are:

1. we only update one table from the view;
2. all the other tables in the view have primary or unique keys so they are guaranteed to return only one row.
3. the unique columns must be referenced in the view

If the update does not fulfil these strictures it will hurl `ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table`.

It's not clear why you want to use a WITH clause but that may make it harder to ensure you're using key-preserved tables.  For instance this variant on the above query fails, even though we know DUAL always returns one row.

```
update 
    ( with tmp as ( select c.col2 
                    from table_c c
                          join dual d
                          on d.dummy = c.col2)
    select a.col1 as a_col1
           , b.col1 as b_col1
           , a.id as a_id
    from tmp
         join table_b b
             on b.col2 = tmp.col2
         join table_a a
             on a.col3 = b.col3
     ) t
set a_col1 = b_col1
/
```

---

If this explanation does not help you arrive at a solution please *edit your question* to provide more details.   Include any error messages you get.  "i can't success" is not enough information for us to help you.

---

> "I was use your answer that called /*+ bypass_ujvc */ "

That is an undocumented hint, so it's pretty risky to use in Production.  Also, it seems [Oracle removed it in 11gR2](https://community.oracle.com/message/9905215#9905215) and later, so it won't have any effect (which is why using undocumented hints is risky).  You should find a solution which works without the hint.

Comment: thanks! I was use your answer that called /*+ bypass_ujvc */  and b_col1 was set key value. appreciate @APC ! have a nice everydays!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help as you didn't provide enough information. However with result can be update in below way:

```
update  (
  with temp as (
                select col1 from table_a 
                )
   select col1 from temp )
set col1 = 'newValue'
```

Comment: Thanks but i can't success. I will do this try more~